# Using JWT with SFDX Not working

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I try running the following command

```
sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid XXXXX --username XXXXXX --jwtkeyfile /server.key --setdefaultdevhubusername
```

I created the connected app on my Salesforce production account and the following Error I get is this

```
This session is not valid for use with the REST API.
```

Anyone have some clues?

Comment: Does the user as whom you are authenticating have permission to access the API?

Comment: @DavidReed I've checked everywhere to give the user access. Not sure If I've missed any settings. Also i'm pretty new to salesforce

Comment: Try adding the scope "api" to the connected app